# Mongo DB update through Ajax using Laravel

Tags: jquery, ajax, mongodb, laravel-5

I am trying to perform an update operation in mongo db through ajax. My data is being displayed through the following view, and I use jquery sortable for dragging data from one column to another.It all works fine, and I also have a callback function which provides me the task id along with the column headers its being dragged through.

```
 <table id="sort1">
                    <thead >
                    <tr >

                        @foreach($tasks as $status => $task)
                        <td id="{{$status}}"><strong>{{$status}}</strong><br><br>
                       <table id="sort"  style="table-layout: fixed;width: 180px;">  
                        <tr ><td id="{{$status}}" style="table-layout: fixed; background-color: Cornsilk  ; ">Drop the task here</td> </tr>

                        </table>


                          @foreach($task as $key => $list)

                        <table id="sort"  style="table-layout: fixed;width: 180px;">  
                        <tr ><td id=""{{$list['_id']}} style="table-layout: fixed; background-color: Cornsilk  ; ">Summary:{{$list['summary']}}<br>Milestone ID:{{$list['projectID']}}<br>Assignee:{{$list['assignee']}}<br>Priority:{{$list['priority']}}<br><label  id="{{$list['_id']}}" style="display:none;">{{$list['_id']}}</label></td> </tr>

                        </table>

                         @endforeach

                        </td>

                        @endforeach
                    </tr>
                    </thead>

                </table> 


            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Jquery/Javascript:

```
<script>


$( function() {
$("table #sort").sortable({
    tolerance: "intersect",
    connectWith: "table #sort",
    dropOnEmpty: "true"

}).disableSelection();
});

$( "table #sort" ).sortable({
 start: function(event, ui) {
        var line = ui.item.closest('td').text();
        var new_status = line.split('\n')[0];
        console.log(new_status);
  }
});


$ (function() {
$( "table #sort" ).sortable({
 receive: function(event, ui) {
        var line = ui.item.closest('td').text();
        var new_status = line.split('\n')[0];
        console.log(new_status);
        var objid = ui.item.find('label').html()
        console.log(objid);
}


});

});
</script>
```

I have very little to no knowledge in ajax,but I would now like to update database through ajax , wherein I would basically be updating the task status, when I drag a given task from one column(status) to another, through its object id.I am assuming that I would have to provide the url of my update function in the controller, but am unable to understand how to proceed with the same. Would really appreciate any suggestions regarding the same.

Answer (score 0):

Referring the laravel documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#updates ,I used a simple update statement using the where clause and passing the ObjectId of the data to be updated as the parameter, and was able to perform the update operation.